# Unable to fetch image in Listview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch image from server using Picasso but it shows error in my logcat saying that :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.foo.o, PID: 3294
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
                      at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
                      at com.example.foo.isfoo.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:44)
```

This is my java code:

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lecturer>{
        ArrayList<Lecturer> lecturers;
        Context context;
        int resource;
        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Lecturer> lecturers) {
            super(context, resource, lecturers);
            this.lecturers=lecturers;
            this.context=context;
            this.resource=resource;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lecturer_list,null,true);
            }
            Lecturer lecturer=getItem(position);
   //logcat indicate problem from picasso 
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lec_Image);
            Picasso.with(context).load(lecturer.getImage()).into(imageView);

            TextView lecName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lecturer_Name);
            lecName.setText(lecturer.getName());

            TextView lecID=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lec_ID);
            lecID.setText(lecturer.getID());

            TextView lecPass=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lec_Pass);
            lecPass.setText(lecturer.getPassword());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Appreciate if you can teach me how to solve this problems.

Comment: getItem(position) where is methed?

Answer (score 0):

Your image path should be not empty and not null, here your try to pass empty or null value so only show this error.

You can try this way it will work

```
String imagePath = "temp image path";
if(lecturer.getImage()!=null&&!lecturer.getImage().equals(""){
imagePath=lecturer.getImage();
}
Picasso.with(context).load(imagePath).into(imageView);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, what should i put in "temp image path"?

Comment: Picasso tries to load some URL. if ur pass null or empty how could load that? so, in this case, you should pass some temporary string as a path

Comment: Still not able to fetch, i have put the URL String imagePath= "http://fsystem.com/ ". Because all my image are store in upload folder in db, do I need to write the folder name?

Comment: Actually what is return value in `lecturer.getImage()`, Please check ur autual value.

Comment: I am asking which path have you try to load like "http://www.google.images/djh/dnakddn.png"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by problem. This is another alternative.
Picasso.with(context).load("http://url.com/upload/"+lecturer.getImage()).into(imageView);